# Setting Base Path using ConfigurationBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to set the application base path for a .NET web application I'm building. I keep getting errors on Configuration builder. This is the error I get.

`DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS1061: 'ConfigurationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'SetBasePath' and no extension method 'SetBasePath' accepting a first argument of type 'ConfigurationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I'm assuming I'll get the same error for my `.AddJsonFile()` and `.AddEnvironmentVariables()`. Did I do something wrong? Did I not add the right dependency to my *project.json*? I've enclosed my *startup.cs* and my *project.json*.

#### File *project.json*

```
{
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"compilationOptions": {
"emitEntryPoint": true
},
"tooling": {
"defaultNamespace": "TripPlanner"
},

"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles":  "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration": "1.0.0-beta8",
  "Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0-beta8"
  //"Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "1.0.0-beta8"
},

"commands": {
  "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
},

"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": { },
  "dnxcore50": { }
},

"exclude": [
  "wwwroot",
  "node_modules"
],
"publishExclude": [
  "**.user",
  "**.vspscc"
 ]
}
```

#### File *startup.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions;
using Microsoft.Framework.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection;
using TripPlanner.Services;



namespace TripPlanner
{
  public class Startup
  {
    public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration;

    public Startup(IApplicationEnvironment appEnv){
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
            .AddJsonFile("config.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        #if DEBUG
        services.AddScoped<IMailService, DebugMailService> ();
        #else
        services.AddScoped<IMailService, RealMailService> ();
        #endif
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
       //app.UseDefaultFiles();
       app.UseStaticFiles();
       app.UseMvc(config =>
       {
           config.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
               template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
               defaults: new { controller  = "App", action = "Index"}
           );
       });

    }

    // Entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args) => Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
  }
}
```

The error is in the `public startup` function right near the top of *startup.cs*.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. If you have not yet solved it, try the following 
in the project.json. Add the following:

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0-*",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
```

and it should work

Comment: How t do this in EF Core 2.0 since now there is no project.json file ?

Comment: @ATHER: just add the two nugets the same way you add any other nugets.

Comment: @ATHER `dotnet  add package <packageName>` where packageName in this case is `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions`, or in Visual Studio add nuget package

Comment: Only Json is needed to resolve the issue

Answer (score 80):

I am not sure if anyone still runs into this issue, but I was able to address this in a .NET Core console project (.NET Core app 2.0) via:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
```

Comment: Thanks @bishop.  Adding that in my .net core library solved my problem.

Comment: Yes, installing the `.Json` through NuGet works too.

Answer (score 15):

Try adding the following in your `.csproj` file:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.2.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions and Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json are exactly the packages that are missing.

Comment: this answer also applies to .Net 6

Comment: FileExtensions and Json were missing, now working for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

One more possible issue...

I had to add this:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="3.0.0" />
```

in order for this to compile:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
  ...
```

I'm pretty sure it was for a console app.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 5):

If you’re running a **.NET Core 1.x** or **.NET Standard 1.x**, you should run this command:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json -v 1.1.1
```

If your project is inside another folder:

```
dotnet add .\src\MyProject package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json -v 1.1.1
```

...where *MyProject* is the name of the `.csproj` file.

Answer (score 5):

Something else to consider:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
```

Without that "using" statement, it doesn't find the extension method in Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.

The trouble cropped up for me because we were also:

```
using System.Configuration;
```

And there was a name clash with "ConfigurationBuilder". 
Add the

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
```

line... remove the

```
using System.Configuration;
```

line, then fully qualify anything under System.Configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to your project.json dependencies:

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0-*",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-*",
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried adding both to the project.json and then did a "dnu restore". But I'm still getting the same error in my Startup.cs. Any other ideas? I found the documentation for the exact function I'm using **[here](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/1.0.0-beta8/src/Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.FileExtensions/FileConfigurationExtensions.cs)**. `SetBasePath()`

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your project.json:

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0-*"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to your project.json dependencies:
`"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.1.1",`

Or in project.csproj:
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine" Version="1.1.1" />`

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me by adding to the project file in .NET Core 3.1:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

This worked in .NET 6:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, do not forget to set the "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy always" of the JSON file from Properties window.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()             
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsetting.json", 
     Optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
}
```

For the above line of code, **you will need the following NuGet packages:**

```
Microsoft.extensions.configurations
Microsoft.extensions.configurations.json
Microsoft.extensions.Options.configurations
```