# 'Unable to resolve service for type ¨Microsoft.entityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions¨1[LibraryData.LibraryContext] while attempting to activate

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dbcontext

I've run into a problem I cannot solve on my own, so I'm asking for help.

I've recently began learning ASP.NET Core, and wanted to build a library where I have to have a database, login system and administrator powers to be able to add and delete books from the website.

I've created the login system and database, and now I want to add the [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) to the project, but this error pops up:

"'Unable to resolve service for type ¨Microsoft.entityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions¨1[LibraryData.LibraryContext] while attempting to activate "LibraryData.LibraryContext"

This is my code so far...

#### File *LibraryData.LibraryContext.cs*

```
public class LibraryContext : DbContext
{
    public LibraryContext(DbContextOptions<LibraryContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Video> Videos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BranchHours> BranchHour { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Checkout> checkouts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CheckoutHistory> checkoutHistorys { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Holds> holds { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LibraryAsset> LibraryAssets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LibraryBranch> libraryBranches { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LibraryCard> LibraryCards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Status> statuses { get; set; }
}
```

#### File *Startup.cs*

```
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
        services.AddScoped<ILibraryAsset, LibraryAssetService>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddDbContext<LibraryContext>(options
             => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LibraryConnection")));
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<LibraryContext>();
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();
        services.AddScoped<DbContext, LibraryContext>();
        services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

#### File *Program.cs*

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

#### File *AssetIndexListingModel.cs*

```
public class AssetIndexListingModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string AuthorOrDirector { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string DeweyCallNumber { get; set; }
    public string NumberOfPages { get; set; }
    public int DateOfRealease { get; set; }
    public int AgeRes { get; set; }
    public string About { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm suspicious of your second registration for `LibraryContext`. I suspect `services.AddScoped<DbContext, LibraryContext>();` should really be `services.AddScoped<DbContext>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<LibraryContext>());`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've tried it out, but with no luck.

Comment: Try remove the line `services.AddScoped<DbContext, LibraryContext>();` as you already add your context with `services.AddDbContext<LibraryContext>(options...`

Comment: @lordvlad30 i've done that but it doesn't change anything... i've researched this problem further, and to my knowlegde, there is nothing that im doing "wrong" to make this problem happen.

Comment: For lack of a better solution, i had to move the context class to the startup project, that works, but admittedly it is not the best way to do it

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I fixed this error by specifying **--project** and **--startup-project** options to **[Entity Framework Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Framework#History) CLI tools** like this:

```
dotnet ef database update --verbose --project CommandService.Data   --startup-project CommandService
```

**--project** means which project contains the **DbContext** class

**--startup-project** means which project contains the database connection information and other information.

Comment: Also check your ConnectionString for any typos, spaces around semicolons

Answer (score 20):

I recently ran into this issue myself, and this is how I resolved the issue.

In Startup.cs (Configure Services):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Some Code
    services.AddDbContext<LibraryContext>();
    //Some Code
}
```

And then in your DbContext class, instead on passing the DbContextOptions to your base class, configure them as follows.

```
public LibraryContext()
{
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Your Connection String");
}
```

**UPDATE**

The reason for doing it this is because,  [The EF Core Tools only scaffold migrations for the active provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) and if you are creating an SDK style project where the migration assembly is different than the active assembly, configuration can be [overridden in this manner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.onconfiguring?view=efcore-7.0)

Comment: This method worked for me! but instead of the first code block, I used: builder.Services.AddDbContext<LibraryContext>(); in Program.cs

Comment: This worked for me! I was trying to use `AddDbContextPool<context>()` with a single parameterized constructor before but changing to this allowed me to create my migrations.

Comment: it is not available in .net core.

Comment: the above snippet is from .netcoreapp3.1. following nuget packages are required.
EFCore.SQLserver, EFCore.design, EFCore.Tools

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What makes it work? *Why* are these changes necessary? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71507716/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: cont' - Why [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server)? Is that implied or natural? Is it the only option? What about servers during development?

Comment: SQL server was used because it was BobbyGopnik was using this SQL in the original question

Comment: FINALLY, THE ANSWER! The key was to create an EMPTY constructor only. **Correct**: `public YourContext( ) { }`, **Wrong**: `public YourContext(DbContextOptions opts): base(opts) {}`.

Answer (score 10):

Just add an empty constructor for the DbContext and it will fix your problem:

```
public partial class TPPSSDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TPPSSDbContext() { } // This one
    public TPPSSDbContext(DbContextOptions<TPPSSDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You should add code which tells how tools should create DBContext. It is needed when you have DBContext in the class library project referenced to the web project.

```
public class BloggingContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<BloggingContext>
{
    public BloggingContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql();

        return new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/stack-snippets/info) are not for general formatting.

Comment: I really like this solution as it adds the ability to integrate into CI pipeline.

Answer (score 4):

It might not be the solution, but it fixes the issue. Add a ContextFactory for the scaffold tool to pickup on. It is a bit mad that the example just tells you hard code the connection string.

*[From a design-time factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory)*

Answer (score 4):

I got this error using "New Scaffolded Item..." in [Visual Studio 2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2022). Like [Huggster and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70273434/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-%C2%A8microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontextopti/70910020#70910020) [Aytsemik points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70273434/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-%C2%A8microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontextopti/72415994#72415994) out, a solution is to use `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`. If you use [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) with a connection string in `appsettings.json`, this is a complete example:

```
internal class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    ApplicationDbContext IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>.CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new ApplicationDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

If installed in a separate class library then remember to install the [NuGet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet) `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` packages for `ConfigurationBuilder` and `SetBasePath` to work.

Sources:

- *[From a design-time factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory)*
- *[How to use IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementation in ASP.NET Core 2.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50820275/how-to-use-idesigntimedbcontextfactory-implementation-in-asp-net-core-2-1/52418717#52418717)*
- *[Setting Base Path using ConfigurationBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001695/setting-base-path-using-configurationbuilder/38170147#38170147)*

Comment: Thanks. It's works fine when i put this code in my ApplicationDbContext class.

Comment: NOTE: Remember to setup connection string the same as it is in `HostBuilder` Program.cs. (eg. config file or env variable)

Answer (score 3):

Try to modify your context:

```
public LibraryContext(DbContextOptions<LibraryContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
```

to

```
public LibraryContext(DbContextOptions options)
: base(options)
{
}
```

Refer to *[EF Migration Error : Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions #15145](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/15145)*.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I've done that and it seems that it didn't work... at this point i dont really know what else there is to do...

Comment: This fixed my issue. Just had to remove the type argument from `DbContextOptions`. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you must define an empty constructor. As follows;

```
public ApplicationDbContext() {
    // for scaffolding
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a constructor with no parameters solved my problem:

```
public RepositoryContext(DbContextOptions<RepositoryContext> options) : base(options) { }
```

add another one with no parameters

```
public RepositoryContext() { }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I could only resolve the issue by choosing `Developer Command Prompt` instead of `Developer PowerShell` in Visual Studio. I had 2 projects in the solution for Startup and Infrastructure. I followed the following pattern.

To create migration:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --project <Project_contains_the_DBContext> --startup-project <Startup_project>
```

To update the DB:

```
dotnet ef database update --project <Project_contains_the_DBContext> --startup-project <Startup_roject>
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking for a good two hours for this problem, I found a fix. It turned out that I had ADO.NET Entity Framework 8.0.0, and I had to downgrade to 7.0.9.

It worked like a charm then.

Comment: -please provide code

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had this problem when I was trying to register my custom Unit of Work service. Here is how I solved it:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<KioskAdminDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(CnStr)); // Usual db context registration
builder.Services.AddScoped<DbContext, KioskAdminDbContext>(); // This is what I added

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(); // My custom service
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Provide context configuration in using dbcontextoptionsbuilder in the OnConfigure method of your DBcontext.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using Clean Code Architecture which encountered this error on first migration.

I went to Web Project > Right Click > Set as Startup Project and it fixed the error.
[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio setting Project as Startup]

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because of an incorrectly formed appsettings.json file. There was an extra { where it doesn't need to be. Check if there're any warnings on the appsettings.json file.

Answer (score 0):

When I choose "Set as startup project" the problem is solved in .NET 8.

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataBaseContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlConnection"))
);
```