# Unable to add migration: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions'

Tags: asp.net-core, migration, entity-framework-migrations

When attempting to add a migration for my .net core 6.0 project, I get the following error:
No static method 'CreateHostBuilder(string[])' was found on class 'Program'.
No application service provider was found.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Found DbContext 'ApplicationDbContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions' while attempting to activate 'DataAccess.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.

My project structure looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3WXF.png)

with my dataacess project containing my code first structure, my ApplicationDbContext code is:

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
    : base(options)
    {
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext() { }


    public DbSet<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Column> Columns { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DevopsBoard> DevopsBoards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DevopsBug> DevopsBugs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Priority> Priorities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Severity> Severities { get; set; }

}
```

I have tried the following options in the EF cli:
add-migration first -startupproject dataaccess  -verbose

add-migration first -Project issuemaster  -startupproject dataaccess  -verbose

Can anybody give me some guidance?

I have tried the stuff on: ['Unable to resolve service for type ¨Microsoft.entityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions¨1[LibraryData.LibraryContext] while attempting to activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70273434/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-%C2%A8microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontextopti)

Comment: Hi, pls check if you have followed this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Answer (score 0):

What worked for my case is that I've added Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design for my startup project and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, *Tool, and *SqlServer have been installed into the Infrastructure project

and after that run the migration