# Unable to create an object of type AppdbContext. i ran into this issue many times

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider in assembly 'RpositoryPatternDB'...
Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
Using environment 'Development'.
Using application service provider from Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Found DbContext 'AppDbContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions' while attempting to activate 'RpositoryPatternDB.DAL.AppDbContext'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

please let me know how to resolve this issue i am using .net core 6.0 and packages of 7.0 version  and In program.cs file there is no main method all is latest version

```
public class AppDbContext:DbContext
{     
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {

        }
       
        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PersonAddress> PersonAddresses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PersonContact> PersonContacts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PersonBankDetail> PersonBankDetails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Car> Car { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CarVarient> CarVarients { get; set; }
}
```

Register:

```
var app = builder.Build(); 
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebAppDBConnection")); });
```

Comment: How did you register your AppDbContext class?

Comment: var app = builder.Build();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebAppDBConnection"));
});

Comment: try constructor: `public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) {  }`

Comment: Still facing same error i have tried many other solutions as well

Comment: There is a possible related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70273434/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-%C2%A8microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontextopti

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your registration order, please move the registered code before `builder.Build()`:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebAppDBConnection")); });
var app = builder.Build();
```

Comment: yes it sorted the problem.....