# Visual Studio unable to resolve service for type foo while attempting to activate bar

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design

I'm writing a To do list program using DDD, and this error comes up whenever I try to use scaffolding to make CRUD pages for the ToDo items

Here is part of `Program.cs`:

```
        builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        builder.Services.AddInfrastructure();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ITDRepository, ITDRepository>();
```

Here is `AddInfrastructure()`, which is in a different project from `program.cs`:

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<TDContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("Some long-ass SQL name", b => b.MigrationsAssembly("FirstDDD")));

            services.AddScoped<ITDRepository, TDRepository>();
            return services;
        }
```

The `ToDo.cs` class:

```
    public class ToDo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Finally, TDContext:

```
    public class TDContext : DbContext
    {
        public TDContext(DbContextOptions<TDContext> options):base(options)
        {
            
        }
        public DbSet<ToDo> ToDos { get; set; }
    }
```

More possibly relevant info:

I added in `builder.Services.AddScoped<ITDRepository, ITDRepository>()` after reading other questions related to this subject, but it did not help.

The solution is made up of four projects (FirstDDD, Application, Domain, Infrastructure), and TDContext is described in Infrastructure, then activated in `program.cs`

Could be unrelated, but does the fact that my Migration code assembles in FirstDDD while the context sits in Infrastructure matter at all?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with this line `services.AddScoped<ITDRepository, ITDRepository>();`. The second parameter of the `AddScoped` method should be the concrete implementation type (`TDRepository` in your case) rather than the interface (`ITDRepository`).

So changing line to `services.AddScoped<ITDRepository, TDRepository>();`  should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but fixing that issue doesn't get rid of the problem. The exact error, which I didn't include in the post because I am stupid, is:

"There was an error running the selected service for type Microsoft.EntityCoreFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Infrastructure.TDContextFolder.TDContext] while attempting to activate Infrastructure.TDContextFolder.TDContext"

is that relevant at all or am I at a dead end?

Comment: @GooseyLoosey I have tried to answer the question based on the problem you have posted. so now you are asking a completely different question. so I would suggest you post a new question. This may help you for the new problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/71842300/6527049