# Trouble with add-migration (Entity Framework Core)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

Trying to run `add-migration` for a code-first database, but I'm getting this error:

> Unable to create an object of type 'StoreContext'.

This is the error messages with `-verbose`:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[КПО_лаб_2._3.StoreContext]' while attempting to activate 'КПО_лаб_2._3.StoreContext'.
>
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
> End of inner exception stack trace ---

Here's my context code:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace КПО_лаб_2._3
{
    public class StoreContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }

        public StoreContext(DbContextOptions<StoreContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;Database=Store;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=Yes;Trusted_Connection=True");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // Настройка связей между сущностями

            // Связь "Клиент" (Client) - "Заказ" (Order) (1-*)
            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .HasOne(o => o.Client)
                .WithMany(c => c.Orders)
                .HasForeignKey(o => o.ClientId);

            // Связь "Заказ" (Order) - "Детали заказа" (OrderDetail) (1-*)
            modelBuilder.Entity<OrderDetail>()
                .HasOne(od => od.Order)
                .WithMany(o => o.OrderDetails)
                .HasForeignKey(od => od.OrderId);

            // Связь "Товар" (Product) - "Детали заказа" (OrderDetail) (1-*)
            modelBuilder.Entity<OrderDetail>()
                .HasOne(od => od.Product)
                .WithMany(p => p.OrderDetails)
                .HasForeignKey(od => od.ProductId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Unable to resolve service for type ¨Microsoft.entityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions¨1\[LibraryData.LibraryContext\] while attempting to activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70273434/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-%c2%a8microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontextopti)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by adding empty constructor like this:

```
public partial class TPPSSDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TPPSSDbContext() { } //this one
    public TPPSSDbContext(DbContextOptions<TPPSSDbContext> options) 
        : base(options) 
    { 
    }
}
```

i also added -project to add-migration so it lookes like this:
add-migration abc -project КПО_лаб_2.3