# Create an ASP.NET Core MVC application with database-first approach

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, database-first

I want to create an ASP.NET Core MVC application. It seemed it was no good idea to use a .NET Framework project, since the abandon of Entity Framework 6.

So, I try .NET Core, and I read this:
[Entity Framework Core (EF Core) Database First Approach - Dot Net Tutorials](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/entity-framework-2-with-net-mvc-database-first/)

I installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`, and now I type

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;Trust Server Certificate=True"
```

In the Nuget Package console, I am answered that `Scaffold-DbContext` is not a recognized applet command name, script, command ...

If, just in case, I try the same in the "Immediate" window, I am answered that Data is not a valid format specifier (CS0726).

In the "Add, New Element" contextual menu entry, I have no "Entity Data Model Wizard".

Do you see what I missed ?

I'm using

- Visual Studio 2022 Community
- Windows 11
- SQL Server 2014 Express

Comment: I am asking another question elsewhere, and I come back when it is solved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78150498/mvc-selecting-the-controller

Answer (score 1):

Since .net core doesnt *easily* support scaffolding, someone create a extension for visual studio caller [EF Core Power Tools](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools), I will suggest that you take a look

It can reverse engineer the selected database, creating the dbcontext and model with custom option

I have used it in many, many applications and so far it work nicely

Comment: I installed that and yes, a new "Data" category appeared in "Insert, new object".
It seems I now have to learn how to use that, it is not so intuitive as that.

Comment: Much clearer after having seen the video :)
Still have a service not available, but it seems on a good trail.

Comment: Well, with the "EF Core Power Tools" contextual menu entry, I could obtain a DbContext and a class for the object to extract (reverse engineering).
There was an attempt to use Docker, and then in another project I try without it.

Comment: When trying to create a controller, I have an error while executing the selected code generator : "
« Method not found: 'Void
Microsoft. EntityFrameworkCore. Storage. RelationalTypeMapping.. ctor(Syst
em.String, System. Type, System.Nullable' 1<System.Data.DbType>,
Boolean, System.Nullable' 1<1nt32>, Boolean, System.Nullable' 1<1nt32>
System.Nullable' 1<1nt32>)'. »"

Did I forget to check a checkbox ?

Answer (score 0):

For Asp.net-core project to use `Scaffold-DbContext` You need to install following packages:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

And the ASP.NET Core doesn't support "ADO.Net Entity Data Model Wizard". It can only be used in old .NET framework project.

I suggest you try this sample https://medium.com/@certosinolab/exploring-database-first-approach-with-entity-framework-in-net-core-6-db86a822d72e

Comment: Silly question from someone who has not used .Net for a while. Is it normal for these to not already be installed? Or is this some edge case?

Comment: @Nick.Mc Not silly. These packages are needed only when doing migration(db 1st or code 1st). For normal connection only need  "...core.sqlserver".

Comment: I should say I have those references , although I am only able to give you the list in a screen copy (is there a better way ?)
Is Microsoft.VisualStudio.web.CodeGeneration.Design OK for the second to last ? Maybe this is the point.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, I eventually displayed the data from the table, although the connection string was stored in a not really recommended place.

Mainly I used elements given in this thread, and also [the search result about "service not found" (in substance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70273434/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-%C2%A8microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontextopti).

After that, my machine crashed, I had to reinstall many things, and the new Program.cs contains less elements than I remember from yesterday, and the context is not found to run the command I just mentioned.

So, I shall come back, maybe in a week or so, to provide a more complete answer.

It is not impossible I have to ask for guidance in the interval, but with no doubt it will be much clearer in a different thread.