# ASP.NET Core MVC : Selecting the controller

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, port

I created an ASP.NET Core MVC application with EF Core.

Several problems appeared one after the other. I eventually could create a controller on the orders table of Northwind database. It went with views automatically.

When launching the application, this opened the `HomeController`, that is provided by default.

As I want to open the `OrdersController`, in the address bar, after

```
https://localhost:7290/
```

I add `orders`, but I get a transient error, whereas the content has this property :

```
.UseSqlServer(
            @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFMiscellanous.ConnectionResiliency;Trusted_Connection=True",
            options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                maxRetryCount: 5,
                maxRetryDelay: System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                errorNumbersToAdd: null)
            );
```

I first tried with nothing in the parenthesis for `EnableRetryOnFailure`, and then tried something I saw in the forums. Well the example was on MySql, as I use SQL Server Express, perhaps good to know.

The database is on an instance of SQL Server Express rather than on `localdb`, but I am not sure this is the point.

I remember that the two controllers can target two ports, how do I verify that?

And supposing it is not the point either, what must I do?

Comment: The port is for the web application not just one controller, could you please tell me why you want to use different port for different controller?

Comment: I do not specially want a different port, but I want to open my application, not only the default application proposed with the project type.
And I get an authentication error against the database, although it is supposed to use the Windows authentication. I open the database in SSMS with no problem.

Comment: I can also display the data of the table from the server explorer, in Visual Studio.

Comment: If in the code I just put options.EnableRetryOnFailure(), then on the results page I get "An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure' to the 'UseSqlServer' call." And further on the page : cannot open the database - the login failed.

Comment: After expanding a node on the results page, I see error 4060. It seems this links to a whole range of documentation.

Comment: SQL Server Express has recently been reinstalled. I am searching how to enable the distant access to the database.

Comment: Remote connection is enabled.

Comment: A WinForms application accesses the same table.

Comment: I have a doubt about the connection string.
        "MVCcumul07Context1": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MVCcumul07Context-d8947c2a-1425-4ec2-87c8-2621e79ea868;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;timeout=120;",
        "MVCcumul07Context": "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;Trust Server Certificate=True"
The first one was automatically created by the application. The second one is what is provided by the server explorer. I changed it, and now the error is different : Order is an invalid object name.

Comment: This means that this time the database has been accessed, and there is an error somewhere in the code. Do I interpret correctly ?

Comment: The new error occurs while executing this procedure:         public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var MVCcumul07Context = _context.Order.Include(o => o.Customer);
            return View(await MVCcumul07Context.ToListAsync());
        }

Comment: As it is another error, I presume I have to open another thread?

Answer (score 0):

As appears in the comments, my question was motivated by a false track, I wondered whether I had to use another port, but in fact the connection string was false.
The platform automatically proposes a connection string after selecting a database in a list, but this connection string was false: it targeted localdb, whereas the database was on a SQL Server instance.
After using the connection string that is provided by the server explorer, the results page still displayed an error, but no more the same one.
"Order" is not a correct object name, this leads to think the connection is established, and I have to scan my application to situate an error on the object name. Maybe I shall open another thread.