# Unable to resolve service for dbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

To obtain an ASP.NET Core MVC web site, after a crash, I follow the indications of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78058290/create-an-asp-net-core-mvc-application-with-database-first-approach/78058703#78058703) again.

I installed the Visual Studio extension, I inserted the four Entity Framework Core references, I typed `dotnet ef database update` and so on according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70273434/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-%C2%A8microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontextopti), after replacing the name of the `DbContext` by the correct value.

And I read the answer, with the errors on white background when any.

(is there anything I have to search in the solution, to verify this step is executed correctly ?)

And now, I am taking care of "unable to resolve service on dbContext" error in what follows, and given the number of different tries I made, it seems it could help that somebody can point out that error more precisely, before I am able to write a concise synthesis. After that I shall take care of storing the connection string in a more confidential place, but first getting the data on the web page could be an interesting step.

As you understand, I could create an orders controller, but when I try to display its Index page, I obtain the error

> "InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'MVCcumul_01.Models.NorthwindContext' while attempting to activate 'MVCcumul_01.Controllers.OrdersController'.
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ThrowHelperUnableToResolveService(Type type, Type requiredBy)

I verified the connection string (that error appeared in a past try). Data appears properly from the servers explorer in Visual Studio 2022 Community, and/or from SSMS 19.1, on Windows 11 Version 23H2 (OS build 22631.3296)

I first forgot about declaring `AddDbContextFactory` in `ConfigureServices`, then declared both it and `NorthwindContext` as singleton, then both as scoped (that should have both worked), then mixed (that was not supposed to work, or perhaps I mixed up, but not to ... waste the travel).

Here is the code:

`Startup.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MVCcumul_01.Models;

namespace MVCcumul_01
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connectionString = @"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServer²Certificate=True";

            services.AddDbContext<NorthwindContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString),
                ServiceLifetime.Singleton);

            services.AddDbContextFactory<NorthwindContext>(
               options => options.UseSqlServer(),
                lifetime: ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
        }

        public void Configure()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using MVCcumul_01;

// EF Core uses this method at design time to access the DbContext
static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(
            webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()); 

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

`ApplicationDbContextFactory.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MVCcumul_01.Models
{
    internal class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<NorthwindContext>
    {
        NorthwindContext IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<NorthwindContext>.CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<NorthwindContext>();
            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

            builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

            return new NorthwindContext(builder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "MVCcumul_01Context1": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MVCcumul_01Context-bfca8e78-d989-4ba3-a265-435e16ece2bb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
        "MVCcumul_01Context": "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;Trust Server Certificate=True"
    }
}
```

Comment: JFY you don't need to register both Context and ContextFactory, if factory (and context) is needed the c calling `AddDbContextFactory` is enough.

Comment: As I read, right that both are not needed, declaring ContextFactory as Singleton was mentioned, and as an alternative, change the lifetime of Context.
So, as did not reach the aim, I quoted the whole code and then it is more simple to put a part in comment, or give the lifetime that is compatible.
I just began to read, so maybe I am going to try several things amongst this.

Comment: About code formatting, it seems I have to get some tips. I had a great margin at the beginning of each module, I deleted the empty line at the beginning, and then was reproached not to have put a left margin. So I put the empty line at the beginning again, and it was published. But, true, with a strange aspect.

Comment: I saw an answer to this appear. I shall have to take some time to get the subtleties of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> // EF Core uses this method at design time to access the DbContext

It does and it does not. EF Core works just fine with the default minimal hosting model (the one used by templates i.e. `var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);`).

Remove the `Startup` (it is not actually used by your app so it does not have context registered) and the `CreateHostBuilder` method and register context with `builder.Services`, so you app can actually use it:

```cs
// ideally read connection string from the config
// builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
builder.Services
   .AddDbContextFactory<NorthwindContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(...));
```

And please do not register database context as singleton in general case it will cause a lot of problems.

See also:

- [Migrating code to minimal hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-8.0)
- [.NET Generic Host in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Comment: So, as you see, I have ``var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);``
So, you mean some code I put in Startup.cs is redundant with this. You mean I have just to put Startup.cs out of the project? Hum, if I knew, I should not have put it. I had to tempt something to solve the error.

Comment: Applying what is said in the answer, I now have in Program.cs : ``var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services
   .AddDbContextFactory<NorthwindContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
``
I am afraid an error says me that DbContextOptionsBuilder contains no definition for UseSqlServer.
It seems I am going to sleep some time, and have a look back. There is still reading to do also, as I see.

Comment: @user3500176 it means that the project should have correct nuget installed.

Comment: This is what I have : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (9.0.0-preview.2.24128.4)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design (9.0.0-preview.2.24128.4)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sq1Server (9.0.0-preview.2.24128.4)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (9.0.0-preview.2.24128.4)
Microsoft.V1sua1Studio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design (8.0.2)

Comment: @user3500176 without seeing the full code/project structure/how ef commands are invoked  it is hard to tell. Also is there any particular reason why do you use preview versions instead of LTS?

Comment: I got this data by screen copy, thus strange characters in the character recognition

Comment: Perhaps a strong typing can help ?

Comment: @user3500176 TBH I don't understand. Strong typing?

Comment: I have just searched for a way ... You mean I could have copied from the project file ?

Comment: Yes, var can be anything ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257246/discussion-between-user3500176-and-guru-stron).

Comment: Project is now shared there :
https://github.com/Gluups/MVCcumul_01_

Comment: I still tried something. In Program.cs :
builder.Services.AddDbContext<NorthwindContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
From that point, the application begins having interest in the connection string. After deleting the spaces in TrustServerCertificates, this time I have an instance failure.

Comment: @user350017 I have looked at your code. It was missing `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`. Just add it and as suggested in the answer everything will work as expected.

Comment: Program.cs begins like this : using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using MVCcumul_01;
using MVCcumul_01.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Configuration;
I also have "using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" at the beginning of Startup.cs,, of NorthwindContext.cs, of OrdersController.cs
But I presume you see that on Github. I wonder where I can have forgotten it.
I precise that the server explorer has no problem.

Comment: But you are right that it does not appear on Github. I am launching a push ...

Comment: Oh, I have got a synchronisation problem. After two Push, I still do not have Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore in Program.cs on Github, whereas I have it in Visual Studio.

Comment: Got it. But still instance failure.

Answer (score 0):

UseSqlServer is a property of the options of Services, more precisely of its AddDbContextFactory method.
So, when this was noticed, the syntax to use happened to be the one quoted by Guru Stron:

```cs
builder.Services
       .AddDbContextFactory<NorthwindContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(...));
```

After that, I had an instance failure.
This key word has to be searched for, separately, and then the first answer is the good one.

Pay attention to the connection string in Program.cs:

```cs
var connectionString = @"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True";
```

@ at the beginning is the mark of a Verbatim string, it means that the string is going to be transmitted "as is".
Without it, \ means the beginning of an escape sequence, this is why you must escape it if you put one in the string.
In a Verbatim string, you do not escape characters.

So, one of both following syntaxes can be used:

```cs
var connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True";

var connectionString = "Data Source=.\\\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True";
```

and then, the data is displayed on the web page.

Comment: I presume it is a good idea to take the Github repository offline in a few days?

Comment: ... Like that ?